# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de fondo de un Scaffold de manera más fluida? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

En una pagina1 que tiene una imagen con un widget Hero cambio a pagina2 que igual tiene un widget hero para que se haga la animacion en la imagen al cambiar de página, después lo que hago es que al cambiar a pagina2 obtengo primero la imagen, después obtengo el color dominante de la imagen y lo guardo en una variable y por último cambio el fondo de la página2 con el color dominante de la imagen.
El problema es que al cambiar de pagina1 a pagina2 se traba mucho, la app no va fluida al momento de aplicar el fondo.
Supongo que es por el setState que puse para cambiar el fondo, pero no he encontrado otra forma.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:palette_generator/palette_generator.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import '../resources/firestore_methods.dart';
import '../utils/color_utils.dart';

class FullViewPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map post;
  const FullViewPostScreen({Key? key, required this.post}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FullViewPostScreenState createState() => _FullViewPostScreenState();
}

class _FullViewPostScreenState extends State<FullViewPostScreen> {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final firebase = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  Map<String, dynamic> post = {};
  Color dominantColor = Colors.white;
  late StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  getData() {
    streamSubscription = firebase
        .collection("POSTS")
        .doc(widget.post['postId'].toString())
        .snapshots()
        .listen((value) async {
      final paletteGenerator = await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
        Image.network(
          value.data()!['postUrl'].toString(),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ).image, 
      ); //aqui obtengo los colores de la imagen

      setState(() { //este es el setState que creo que da algo de problema
        post = value.data()!;
        dominantColor = paletteGenerator.dominantColor!.color.withOpacity(0.8); //aqui pongo en dominant color el color dominante de la imagen
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    streamSubscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            title: const Text('Post'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
        backgroundColor:
            dominantColor != Colors.white ? dominantColor : Colors.transparent, //aqui pongo de fondo el color dominante
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 59.h,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                   
                      child: Hero(
                        tag: "image",
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.network(
                            widget.post['postUrl'].toString(),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //auto size text
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                        widget.post['quote'],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                        )
                ),
                // iconos de me gusta y comentarios
     
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: en este video lo explico :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz37oYILv5k

Comment: Muchas gracias ;l